# How to make multiple replacements in HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, replace

I have JavaScript code for replacing **text** or **link** in HTML, but the code only works for single **replacement**. I need to replace many **text** & **link** in my HTML code.

```
var search = "Selena";
var replacement = "Love";

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.split(search).join(replacement);
```

Comment: Do you want only to replace 'Selena' with 'Love'?

Comment: i have many words to replace example
Selena with love
mical with jhon
sara with nida
jhoony with joona

this code only work for 1 replacement.

Comment: Don't use regexp to modify the HTML of the body. Among other things, you will lose any attached event handlers.

Comment: @torazaburo in fact, even the code in the question would result in the same loss :p even though there's no regex

Comment: It should work with split and join like you did it. Even with multiple replacements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it with Regex.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Selena/g,"Love")
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: regex on html alert :p I hear Zalgo's hoof prints approaching!

Comment: @ArslanKhalid Why would you accept this answer when it does not show how to do what you say you want, which is to do multiple search/replaces?

Comment: how is this in any way a different result from the question?

Answer (score 1):

With a little prep work you can use [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to do this without effectively overwriting the whole DOM - which is slow, and you lose any event listeners added to elements

```js
var replacements = {
    'Selena': 'Love',
    'mical': 'jhon',
    'sara': 'nida',
    'jhoony': 'joona'
};
var keys = Object.keys(replacements);
var regex = new RegExp(keys.join('|'),'g');
var replacer = function(str) {
    return str.replace(regex, function (key) {
        return replacements[key];
    });
}
    
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT|NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, { 
        acceptNode: function(node) {
            // only processing non-empty text nodes, and <A> with non empty href
            if ((node.nodeName == '#text' && node.nodeValue) || (node.nodeName == 'A' && node.href)) {
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; 
            }
            // Skip this node, but still consider its child nodes
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
        } 
    },
    false
);

while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    var node = treeWalker.currentNode;
    var replace;
    if (node.nodeName == '#text') {
        node.nodeValue = replacer(node.nodeValue);
    } else {
        node.href = replacer(node.href);
    }
}
```

```html
<span>Selena
    <b>mical</b>
    sara
    <a href='#jhoony'>Link to #jhoony</a>
</span>
```

Comment: very very good point @torazaburo - I always forget about TreeWalker as I don't do this sort of "stuff" much at all :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**regex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that has `g`(global) flag to replace all occurs. 
If you want to **case-insensitive** use `i` flag in regex:

```js
  var search = ["Selena", "jhon sara"];
  var replacement = ["Love", "nida"] ;
  var html = document.body.innerHTML;

  for(var i =0; i<search.length; i++) {
    var search_regex = new RegExp(search[i],"gi");

    html = html.replace(search_regex, replacement[i]);
  }

  document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
Selena is selena. Jhon sara is jhon sara.
```